# Maximum call stack size exceeded in jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm getting this error when trying to validate a form using the jQuery validation plugin.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
    at String.replace (native)
    at TAG (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:6135:36)
    at matcherFromTokens (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:6862:44)
    at Sizzle.compile (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:7016:13)
    at Sizzle.select (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:7102:16)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:5270:9)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:7301:11)
    at a.validator.elements (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:41161:47)
    at a.validator.checkForm (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:41116:76)
    at a.validator.form (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:41114:21)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://myapp.app/js/app.js:41052:105)
```

My validation routine is pretty basic ... not sure why this is happening since all my other forms validate fine.

```
$('#setup-form').validate({
    rules: {
        slim: {
          required: true,
        },
        role: {
          required: true,
        },
        gender: {
          required: true,
        },
        orientation: {
          required: true,
        },
        ip_address: {
          required: true,
        },
        about: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 20,
          maxlength: 5000,
        },
        looking: {
          required: true,
        },
        seeking: {
            required: true,
        },
        status: {
          required: true,
        },
        age: {
          required: true,
        },
        ethnicity: {
          required: true,
        },
        education: {
          required: true,
        },
        body: {
          required: true,
        },
        height: {
          required: true,
        },
        hair: {
          required: true,
        },
        eye: {
          required: true,
        },
        piercing: {
          required: true,
        },
        tattoo: {
          required: true,
        },
        smoking: {
          required: true,
        },
        drinking: {
          required: true,
        }
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Since there is nothing wrong with the validation code, perhaps also show the relevant HTML so we at least have a chance of reproducing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your `errorPlacement` function is not quite right...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
}
```

The `errorPlacement` function is only meant for *placing* the error message element within the HTML markup; and your code is merely adding a class.  While I'm not sure if this could be causing your JavaScript error, I am sure that this code is preventing validation messages from appearing.

If you want to toggle classes corresponding to validation, then you should be using the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions.

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
}
```